# Optimize JavaScript conditional class changes

Tags: javascript, optimization, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a more efficient way to write the below, possibly combining the conditions? It's in a scroll event, so I'm trying to minimize my footprint and operations.

Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
if ($win.scrollY >= asideOffsetTopBuffered) {

  aside.classList.add('stuck');
} else {

  aside.classList.remove('stuck');
}

if ($win.scrollY >= articleOffsetBottomBuffered) {

  aside.classList.add('bottom');
} else {

  aside.classList.remove('bottom');
}
```

Comment: I don't see any pattern that can be combined. It looks about as simple as it can get.

Comment: can we conclude that the condition `$win.scrollY >= articleOffsetBottomBuffered` can possibly take place *ONLY* when `$win.scrollY >= asideOffsetTopBuffered` returns true?

Comment: @varnie yes! that's what I was just thinking.

Comment: @technopeasant then you know what can be rewritten;)

Comment: @varnie yeah yeah. I would just nest the second statement into the first... but that can't be great, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more logical to put the conditions as follows:

```
if ($win.scrollY >= asideOffsetTopBuffered) {
    aside.classList.add('stuck');

    //can occur only when the outer condition is met
    if ($win.scrollY >= articleOffsetBottomBuffered) {
        aside.classList.add('bottom');
    } else {
        aside.classList.remove('bottom');
    }
} else {
    aside.classList.remove('stuck');
}
```

But I doubt it will give you any significant performance improvement.